# DatedIff auto result column

Tags: vba, excel

I have this table where i want the  column to automatically find the days of 2 dates of 2 different columns row by row by `datedif` macro, currently I am using `datediff` for the 2 rows resulting in the column.

[image: table]

As you can see i used `datedif` to get results in column f for column b and e between the same row, what I want is every time I enter dates in column b and e, I want column f to automatically show the gap between those 2 days.

As you can see is the case with other days, and it will always be between the same row example it will be b4 with e4 never with b4 and e5, same row with column b and e result showing in column f, which formula for macro can I use to do this. Or any other method that is possible.

Comment: just copy the formula down the column till it covers more than you will ever need.  You could change the formula to `=IF(OR(B4="",E4=""),"",DATEDIF(B4,E4,"D"))` then copy it down a few hundred rows.  As the dates are put into B4 and E4 it will change from a "blank" cell to the date difference.

Comment: i got a few table like you mentioned this time i wanted to do it with macro to create a table differently which is also smoother as if i insert a new row i will have to enter formula again if i have macro then i can insert new rows and i wont have to do anything else

Comment: fwiw, the difference in *days* is a simple subtraction; no need to involve DATEDIF for this if the increment is *number-of-days*.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you don't want to just copy the formula into the rest of the column because that would result in 0 in every row.

What you can do before you copy the formula is check that there are dates in the source columns. If there are you can show the result, if both cells are not populated then you can show an empty string.

Something like this...

```
=IF(AND(B4<>"",E4<>""),DATEDIF(B4,E4,"D"),"")
```

Comment: yes and also because i got a few table like you mentioned this time i wanted to do it with macro to create a table differently which is also smoother as if i insert a new row i will have to enter formula again if i have macro then i can insert new rows and i wont have to do anything else